# access confluence page via python script

Tags: python-3.x, google-oauth, confluence, confluence-rest-api, atlassian-python-api

I need to access a Confluence page via python script, but although I found some examples online, I wasn't able to do it.

Here are a few attempts:

```
import requests

urllogin = 'https://myorg/confluence/display/path/to/page'
login = requests.get(urllogin, auth=('myusername', 'mytoken'))
print(login.status_code)
```

```
from atlassian import Confluence

confluence = Confluence(
    url='https://myorg/confluence/display/path/to/page',
    username='myusername',
    password='mytoken')
```

It doesn't seem to be a token issue: I tried using an Atlassian API token https://id.atlassian.com/manage-profile/security/api-tokens or [Google API token](https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials) (my org uses Google credentials to access Confluence as well). Using login credentials didn't work either.

Answer (score 3):

You have two issues in your attempt.

First, the `url` needs to be the base url of your confluence site, so in your case something along the lines of `url='https://conf.myorg.com'`.

Second, using the parameters `username=` and `password=` is for basic auth. But I guess you want OAuth? Or is the token you are referring to an Atlassian API token? Either way, an [overview of all different authentication modes can be found in the documentation](https://atlassian-python-api.readthedocs.io/index.html). The following examples are taken from there.

OAuth:

```
from atlassian import Confluence

oauth_dict = {
    'access_token': 'access_token',
    'access_token_secret': 'access_token_secret',
    'consumer_key': 'consumer_key',
    'key_cert': 'key_cert'}

confluence = Confluence(
    url='http://localhost:8090',
    oauth=oauth_dict)
```

API token:

```
from atlassian import Confluence

# Obtain an API token from: https://id.atlassian.com/manage-profile/security/api-tokens
# You cannot log-in with your regular password to these services.

confluence = Confluence(
    url='https://your-domain.atlassian.net',
    username=jira_username,
    password=jira_api_token,
    cloud=True)
```